# Cannot execute a program. The command being executed "dqiitg0c.cmdline"

Tags: vb.net, iis, impersonation

i have used impersonation in this application.
whenever this error occurs i required to restart the IIS..
please guide me to solve this issue.

Error:

Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c825d188\1fae8a71\dqiitg0c.cmdline". 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c825d188\1fae8a71\dqiitg0c.cmdline".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of hits when googling this error message.  [This one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315904) looks really good.

Comment: 1) Use a different, non-Anonymous account to impersonate. (This is the recommended method.)
--> We have already impersonating with non anonymous user account

2)Add sufficient permission for the executable files in the Windows directory.
--> for which executable files,i have to provide permissions & with which user?

Comment: csc.exe, the program you're trying to run.  The impersonated user account.